# Using the Facebook C# SDK for Fan Page Custom iFrame Tabs

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to create a simple iFrame custom tab on my fan page.  I'm using the [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) and I need to read the signed_request value that Facebook passes to my iFrame page.

I can print the signed_request encoded value so I know its showing up, but when I try to decode it with the Facebook C# SDK I'm getting an error.  I'm using .NET 4.0 and dynamics.

Here's my code:

signedRequestString contains the Request value with the signed_param passed from Facebook.

```
var result = FacebookSignedRequest.Parse(FacebookContext.Current.AppSecret, signedRequestString);
dynamic signedRequestJson = result.Data;
dynamic page = signedRequestJson.page;
```

And the error I receive:

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference    at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )    at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)    at DecodeSignedRequest(String signedRequestString)
```

Any thoughts why I would be getting a null?  I setup my web.config properly (I think), but I'm guessing I'm missing an initialization step or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast your signedRequestJson object to an `IDictionary` key/value pair before you can grab the page data.

You can do this as follows:

```
dynamic signedRequestJson = result.Data;
var RawRequestData = (IDictionary<string, object>)signedRequestJson;
```

You can then access the page data using the JSON keys (assuming you are referencing the `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` library):

```
Facebook.JsonObject RawPageData = (Facebook.JsonObject)RawRequestData["page"];
currentFacebookPageID = (string)RawPageData["id"];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't end up needed to go quite this far because I simply checked for nulls everywhere and that ended up working.  However, I think this would have worked as well.

Answer (score 3):

It's easier to use FacebookWebContext.Current.SignedRequest.
You can then access the information about the page:

```
if (FacebookWebContext.Current.SignedRequest != null)
{
  dynamic data = FacebookWebContext.Current.SignedRequest.Data;
  if (data.page != null)
  {
    var pageId = (String)data.page.id;
    var isUserAdmin = (Boolean)data.page.admin;
    var userLikesPage = (Boolean)data.page.liked;
  }
  else
  {
    // not on a page
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this. I hope it works for you:

```
Facebook.FacebookConfigurationSection s = new FacebookConfigurationSection();
s.AppId = 'ApplicationID';
s.AppSecret = 'ApplicationSecret';
FacebookWebContext wc = new FacebookWebContext(s);
dynamic da = wc.SignedRequest.Data;
dynamic page = da.page;
string pageid = page.id;
bool isLiked = page.liked;
bool isAdmin = page.admin;
```